# how fix error 500 with flask in apache windows 10

Tags: python, apache, flask, localhost, virtualhost

i'm trying to run a simple flask application on apache24 but in the end i get Internal server error, i'm going to attach my configuration files and code.

httpd.conf

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

at end file im add this:

```
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict

LoadFile "c:/program files/python39/python39.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/program files/python39/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp39-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/program files/python39"
```

httpd-vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    WSGIScriptAlias /SISPRAA "C:/Apache24/htdocs/SISPRAA/main.wsgi"
    <Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/SISPRAA">
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

this is my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_material import Material
from flask_fontawesome import FontAwesome
from pathlib import Path
from flask import send_file
import os
import re
import datetime
from lib.pyReportInfinited import init
from flask import jsonify 


app = Flask(__name__)
Material(app)
fa = FontAwesome(app)
downloads_path = str(Path.home() / "Downloads")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')



@app.route('/makeReport', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def makeReport():

    #print ("init..")
    init()
    return jsonify(msg='end')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

this is main.wsgi:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "C:/Apache24/htdocs/SISPRAA/")

from app import index as application
```

this result error 500 internal server :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmI9L.png)

if i commet last line error not found:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TARWV.png)

if i navigate to localhost only, its okay:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Valfy.png)

apache error.log

```
AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::d972:78ad:5f99:ed39. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Wed Apr 28 19:11:52.022705 2021] [core:warn] [pid 8264:tid 680] AH00098: pid file C:/Apache24/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Apr 28 19:11:52.022705 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8264:tid 680] AH00455: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 28 19:11:52.022705 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8264:tid 680] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Mar 27 2021 11:42:37
[Wed Apr 28 19:11:52.022705 2021] [core:notice] [pid 8264:tid 680] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'
[Wed Apr 28 19:11:52.022705 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8264:tid 680] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 15872
AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::d972:78ad:5f99:ed39. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::d972:78ad:5f99:ed39. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Wed Apr 28 19:11:52.428805 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15872:tid 784] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Apr 28 19:11:57.598808 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 15872:tid 1288] [client ::1:54512] mod_wsgi (pid=15872): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/SISPRAA/main.wsgi'.
[Wed Apr 28 19:11:57.598808 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 15872:tid 1288] [client ::1:54512] TypeError: index() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given\r
```

can anybody help me ? pls

Answer (score 0):

Try to test your httpd.conf file with the command below:

```
httpd -t -f /path/to/httpd.conf
```

and also it would be better if you used backslashes instead of slashes (`\` not `/`) in Windows OS to identify some path in the file system.

Comment: okay, C:\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe -t -f /C:/Apache24/conf
(20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: AH00532: Invalid config file path /C:/Apache24/conf

Comment: say access denied,     C:\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe -t -f C:/Apache24/conf
httpd.exe: Could not open configuration file C:/Apache24/conf: Acceso denegado.

Comment: solution:   from app import app as application in app.py